# configure static/public ip for azure mysql

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mysql-database

Azure has provided the access to the mysql instance as the domain name as 
X.mysql.database.azure.com
I am able to connect it properly. But I need to get the public/static ip address which we can use to access this instance.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot make a static IP address assignment for your Azure SQL Server or Azure Sql Database.

You have to workaround your requirement for static IP address assignment to work with the DNS Name (x.database.windows.net).

Comment: I see. And can you please let me know some workarounds as well. 
So that I can accept you answer.

Comment: Please read this. For static with dns https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2014/03/27/dont-rely-on-a-static-ip-address-for-your-sql-database/